# How to maintain correct order of Login page and Home page with firebase login in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

This may sound very basic. But I couldn't find a way out.

I'm using firebase authentication if this is necessary to know beforehand.

The **initial** view controller is set as `LoginViewController`. I've two buttons here: ***Signup*** & ***Login***. The ***Signup*** button presents another view controller modally where user can opt for signing up. After successful sign-up, the `SignUpViewController` is dismissed, so the `LoginViewController` appears. Inside the `LoginViewController`'s **`viewDidAppear(_:)`** I check for current user and if available redirect user to `HomeViewController`:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let _ = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            // This is a modal segue
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToHomeViewController", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

When tapping **Logout** button in `HomeViewController`, the controller is just dismissed with signing out user.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func logoutButtonDidTouch(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            // This dismiss lands user to the LoginViewController again
            // So user has chance to login again with `Login` button this time
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine so far. But there is a ***subtle misbehavior***. Because every time the app is launched the `LoginViewController` appears and then redirect to `HomeViewController` which isn't so good as user experience.

So, what I want is if the user is logged-in already the first view s/he will see is `HomeViewController` other than `LoginViewController`. But if user didn't log in before, s/he will be landed on the `LoginViewController`.

---

Yes, I could check from the `AppDelegate`'s **`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptionss:)`** for current user and if found, navigate directly to `HomeViewController`. But then I would lose the `LoginViewController` when user taps on **Logout** in `HomeViewController`.

---

At a glance this is pretty much what I need to accomplish:

[image: Signup-Login-Home-Sequence]

> Anything even without the code example is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to check in loadView() function , or you can create an entry view controller with background image like splash screen , make it your initial view and set your check func in viewWillAppear of it's class

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar dilemma, and solved it by adding a 'Splash' `ViewController` as the entry controller for the App.  I have styled it identical to the `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.   In the `SplashVC` I check for a valid User Token and if present it will send direct to the main app (in my case this is a `TabBarController`).  In my `TabBarController` I set a `Firebase` `addStateDidChangeListener` which will direct back to the LoginVC if the User Token ever becomes invalid.

I also use the `Splash VC` to run async code to check subscription status, and write login details to `Firebase`.

Please excuse the quick and dirty schematic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no lose when you logout you can easily show any VC anyTime without a segue , jsut give every viewController an identifier  and set it to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController`

```
let loginView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginView") as! loginVC

let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginView)

nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav
```